# Using IIS URL Rewrite, how to rewrite foo.bar.com -> bar.com/myapp

Tags: iis, rewrite

Our web app lies at bar.com/myapp

We'll use the HTTP Host Header to work out the username

So need to transparently rewrite foo.bar.com to bar.com/myapp using the URL Rewrite module in IIS

But still need to be able to go to www.bar.com and see the company website and webmail.bar.com, etc.

**Got it working:**

Add a server wide Inbound Rule:
Match URL: `(.*)` - check every URL

Condition {HTTP_HOST} `^([^.]+)\.bar\.com` - must be a subdomain of bar.com

Condition {HTTP_HOST} Doesn't Match Pattern: `webmail\.|mail\.` - don't run for webmail. or mail.

Action Rewrite: `myapp/{R:1}` - redirect to /myapp/ keeping all querystring data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REMOVED NON RELEVANT INFO AND EDITED

SO if you are using IIS7 download the [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/). All the instructions and info you need are included at that link.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The subdomain needs to be rewritten, not forwarded. They should be able to browse the website at foo.bar.com/login.html where this is actually bar.com/myapp/login.html

I think that has to be done with some sort or URL rewriting so that all relative images, etc still work and the real URL is masked from the end user

Comment: OK that makes sense then. I edited my post

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. Will edit first post with info to help others

Comment: Good Job! Glad it's working.